# LINQ Group By (VB.net & Linq to Entities)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to get a group by to work in Linq:

```
from document in Documents
  Group Join documentInstrument In DocumentInstruments
      On document.DocumentId Equals documentInstrument.DocumentId
      Into relatedDocumentInstruments = Group
      From documentInstrument In relatedDocumentInstruments.DefaultIfEmpty()
  Group Join instrument In Instruments
      On documentInstrument.InstrumentId Equals instrument.InstrumentId
      Into relatedInstruments = Group
      From instrument In relatedInstruments.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where (document.DocumentId = 1294201 Or document.DocumentId = 1294179)
  Order by instrument.Name
  Select New With
  {
    .Code = instrument.Code,
    .InstrumentName = instrument.Name
  }
```

This basically leaves me with duplicates (same code and name). I have tried pretty much every "Group By" syntax I could find by using google and nothing seems to work.

Here is the original query I am trying to convert to Linq (to entities):

```
Sql = "SELECT Instruments.Name AS Instrument, Instruments.Code, COUNT(Instruments.Name) AS InstrumentCount, " & _
"SUM(Documents.Pages) AS TotalPages, SUM(Fees.FeeAmount) AS FeeAmount " & _
"FROM Documents LEFT JOIN DocInstruments ON Documents.DocID = DocInstruments.DocID AND DocInstruments.IsPrimary = <TRUE /> " & _
"LEFT JOIN Instruments ON DocInstruments.InstrumentID = Instruments.InstrumentID " & _
"LEFT JOIN (SELECT DocumentID, SUM(Amount) AS FeeAmount FROM Transactions WHERE PaymentType = 'Charge' and Void = <FALSE /> " & _
"GROUP BY DocumentID) AS Fees ON Documents.DocID = Fees.DocumentID " & _
"WHERE Documents.DocID IN (" & sList & ") " & sInstWhere & _
"GROUP BY Instruments.Name, Instruments.Code " & _
"ORDER BY Instrument"
```

** I am leaving the join to the Transactions table out of my linq query for the moment and just trying to get the group by on the code/name working before adding more **

EDIT:

Ok, it would be a good start if I could just figure out how to get the following query into linq. I just can't seem to get the join with the group by...

```
SELECT i.Code, i.Name
from Instruments i
LEFT JOIN DocInstruments di on i.InstrumentId = di.InstrumentId
group by i.Code, i.Name
order by i.Code
```

It seems like it shouldn't be that hard, and it's probably not once you know the syntax but I just can't get anything to work and Linqer won't connect to my version of EF. Bummer.

Any linq experts out there that can help?

Comment: I'm not a vb guy but dont all lines have to end with an _ ?

Comment: No. And that is the least of my concerns. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After converting ton of straight SQL queries to LINQ I think I have finally figured out the grouping. So in my question above:

```
SELECT i.Code, i.Name
from Instruments i
LEFT JOIN DocInstruments di on i.InstrumentId = di.InstrumentId
group by i.Code, i.Name
order by i.Code
```

Would be something like this (just typing this here without checking, but this should be close):

```
(FROM instrumentEntity in dbContext.InstrumentEntities
GROUP Join documentInstrumentEntity
    ON instrumentEntity.InstrumentId equals documentInstrumentEntity.InstrumentId Into foundDocumentInstruments = Group
    FROM foundDocumentInstrument in foundDocumentInstruments.DefaultIfEmpty()
SELECT NEW With 
{
.Code = instrumentEntity.Code,
.Name = instrumentEntity.Name
}).GroupBy(Function(result) New With 
    {
    Key result.Code,
    Key result.Name
    }).ToList()
```

When using VB.Net, it is very important that if you are grouping by more than 1 property that you use the "Key" identifier on each field or else the grouping will not work.